# Uso corretto della locuzione "né ... né" con la preposizione "senza"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Se voglio escludere due cose da un concetto che esprimo, posso dire "*né* questo *né* quello". Supponiamo che voglia utilizzare la preposizione *senza*, dovrei allora dire "*senza né* questo *né* quello", oppure va bene anche "*senza* questo *né* quello"?

In poche parole, con "senza" vanno inseriti entrambi i "né" o basta solo quello finale?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Senza né" is not really acceptable in modern Italian because it's a double negation. [Treccani Encyclopedia](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/binomi-irreversibili_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/) only mentions "senza A né B". Linguist [Massimo Arcangeli](http://linguista.blogautore.repubblica.it/2011/08/14/dubbi-sullitaliano-risponde-il-linguista2/) is of the opinion that, although "senza né A né B" is accepted in poetry and literature, it should be avoided. Note that archaic forms like "senza neanche", "senza neppure", "senza nemmeno" or "senza nemmanco" are widely accepted. In modern spoken Italian, "senza né A né B" is usually pronounced with a short pause after "senza" and accompanied by a mimic gesture of the fingers counting the two alternatives, A and B (and possibly others).

According to [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/senza/):

> «5. Quando si escludono due cose, la congiunzione correlativa a senza
>   è né, più raram. o: lo tennero in cella tre giorni, s. mangiare né
>   bere; è uno strozzino, s. pietà né riguardo per nessuno (meno spesso,
>   s. pietà o riguardo).»

So it would be either "senza A né B" or "senza A o B".

They have been talking about it [here](http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=2623) as well.

I think this is an interesting question indeed - it would be nice to read other linguists' point of view.

Answer (score 0):

They are interchangeable:

> Non voglio né amici, né nemici

can also be expressed as

> Non voglio amici, né nemici

This is to say, the first "né" seems to be a *rafforzativo*, even though an extremely common one.

Another example

> Senza "se" e senza "ma"

can also be expressed

> Senza "se", né "ma"

but also

> Senza né "se", né "ma"

or even

> Né "se", né "ma"

They all mean the same thing but have different nuances of strength due to the repetitions.

Answer (score -1):

"senza né questo né quello" non appare essere Italiano corretto, dovendosi in questo caso dire "senza questo e quello", ammesso che abbia senso.

"senza questo né quello" non è malaccio, ma dipendendo dal contesto può avere un'enfasi minore di "né questo né quello", dove il parallelismo fra i due "né" coordina meglio la pari rilevanza dell'assenza di "questo" e "quello".

Comment: Fonte per il "non appare essere italiano corretto"?

Comment: @martina, sorry, non dispongo di altre fonti ad eccezione di me stesso; però, aspettiamo. Chissà se qualcun altro non sia in grado di citare una fonte autorevole, though.

Comment: @martina, hai notato che la answer che hai accettato dice esattamente le stesse cose che ho detto io nella mia risposta?

Comment: già, ma riporta delle fonti ed è più articolata.

Comment: si, cio' e' indiscutibile, e infatti ho castato un upvote!

Comment: @Kyriakos Kyritsis, note that "senza A e B" is not acceptable either. "Senza A né B" and "senza A o B" are OK. "Senza né A né B" is usually pronounced in a different way and has a historic relevance for its poetic and literary flavour (in modern Italian it should probably be avoided).