# Is "senza A e B" acceptable?

Tags: grammar

[It seems](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/uso-corretto-della-locuzione-ne-ne-con-la-preposizione-senza/1447?noredirect=1#comment1932_1447) that "senza A e B" is not acceptable in the Italian language, but "senza A o B" is.

Can anyone explain why?

As far as I can tell, I often hear people saying, for example:

> Sono venuto senza giacca e cravatta.
>
> Questi alimenti sono senza coloranti e conservanti.
>
> Poverino, l'hanno operato senza bisturi ed anestesia.
>
> Le strutture scolastiche campane sono ancore senza assistenza e servizi di trasporto per le persone diversamente abili.
>
> Purtroppo moltissimi giovani sono senza laurea ed esperienza.

and so on.

Are all they wrong?

Comment: "Giacca e cravatta" is certainly an irreversible binomial (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/binomi-irreversibili_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/) so "senza giacca e cravatta" is correct because irreversible binomials are treated as one word.

Comment: I am wondering - maybe the cases you mention are all irreversible binomials (or at least meant to be such): "coloranti e conservanti", "bisturi ed anestesia", "assistenza e servizi", "laurea ed esperienza".

Comment: @random, interesting! I was not aware of this binomial 'rule' which applies here. So the question is what is binomial and what is not, though.

Comment: I'm afraid that's widely arbitrary - I guess any of us is free to propose one: whether the proposed binomial will become of common use or not, that we can't know. Point is it can sound weird if, within a "senza A e B" structure, you treat two words as a binomial and that is not clearly perceived by the receiver of your message. As to the invariability of irreversible binomials, refer to the link above.

Comment: Yes, I think that "giacca e cravatta" is seen as a binomial and therefore is perceived as a single word, "giacca-e-cravatta": this is why "senza giacca e cravatta" is ok (but "senza giacca né cravatta" is anyway correct)

Answer (score 2):

I (politely) disagree with the statement: "that 'senza A e B' is not acceptable in the Italian language, but 'senza A o B' is." Overlooking the fact that the expression is commonly used, as you correctly reported, reason is the following: "e" and "o" are logical connectors so you could build equivalent statements  manipulating the original one by means of logical rules. So cannot be true that, given two propositions P and Q, being P e Q  not acceptable, P o Q is correct. This could seen this way:

NOT (P e Q) <=> NOT(P) OR NOT(Q)

This way we should have two *equivalent* assertions, the first not acceptable, the second perfectly acceptable.  How this could be possible?

Comment: The only exception I can think of is when (A AND B) is a binomial that cannot be inflected: "giacca e cravatta", "senza giacca e cravatta".

Comment: Unfortunately logic rules do not necessarily apply to languages. `NOT(NOT(A)) == A` but often in Italian `NOT(NOT(A)) == NOT(A)` (see http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/why-is-the-double-negation-not-an-issue-in-the-italian-language/)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that neither of them is better than "né".
I think in English you would use "nor", right? (I went without a jacket nor a tie). 
This is much better translated as "né": "Ci sono andato senza giacca né cravatta".
(Just note that "ne" and né" are two different words).

Answer (score 0):

"Senza giacca e cravatta" is different from "senza giacca o cravatta" and it is correct in Italian language. You have just to understand if it means exactly what you want to say. It mean that you don't have both a jacket and a tie. Senza giacca o cravatta" means that you don't have even just one of them.